# В мобильных браузерах не срабатывает метод click() для поля input(форма для отправки файлов)

Tags: javascript, html, форма, safari, mobile-web

Код в индекс хтмл

```
<body>

<form action="upload.php" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px; opacity: 0;" method="post" target="hiddenframe" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="hideBtn();"> 

    <input type="file" id="uploadnewimg" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px" name="userfile" /> 

    <input type="submit" name="upload" style="width:0px; height:0px; border:0px" id="uploadbutton" value="Загрузить" /> 

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" /> 

    </form> 

    <div id="res"></div> 

    <iframe id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe" style="width:0px;     height:0px; border:0px"></iframe>

 </body>
```

Джаваскриптом создаётся див, при нажатии на который выполняется код

```
var input = document.getElementById("uploadnewimg");
input.click();
```

После чего на компьютерах открывается диалоговое окно выбора файла, но вот на safari ios13 и chrome android 5 ничего не происходит.

Как это исправить? Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на див открывалась форма для выбора файла, а после выбора файла, он автоматически отправлялся на сервер(это работает)

Comment: Буквальное нажатие на поле для ввода файла(хоть ширина и высота 0, и его всё равно можно натыкать) открывает диалог выбора на всех устройствах

Comment: программный вызов события `click` не очень желателен

Comment: @meine, спасибо за полезный отзыв, но я бы хотел узнать что в таком случае делать

Comment: При нажатии на какой div вызывается `input.click()`? сделайте воспроизводимый пример. Можно без части отправки файла на сервер.